# Why is grunt-banner options.process() adding multiple file names to my banner?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm learning/setting up grunt into my project workflows and I've been trying to figure out why the grunt-banner options.process() devDependency is adding the subsequent file names to the project files, see below.

Snippet of my Gruntfile.js tasks with regards to grunt-banner:

```
        // Banner inserted at top of the generated files, such a minified CSS
    banner: '/**\n' +
            ' * <%= pkg.name %> - Version <%= pkg.version %>\n' +
            ' * <%= pkg.description %>\n' +
            ' * Author: <%= pkg.author.name %> - <%= pkg.author.email %>\n' +
            ' * Build date: <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss") %>\n' +
            ' * Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author.company %>\n' +
            ' * Released under the <%= pkg.license %> license\n' +
            ' */\n',

    usebanner: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                position: 'top',
                banner: '<%= banner %>',
                linebreak: true,
                process: function( filepath ) {
                    var ndx = 4;
                    var file = " * File: <%= filename %>\n *";
                    var banner = this.banner;
                    banner = [banner.slice(0, ndx), file, banner.slice(ndx)].join('');

                    return grunt.template.process(
                        banner,
                        { data: {
                            filename: filepath.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1]
                        } } );
                }
            },
            files: {
                    src: [ './build/**/*.js', './build/**/*.css' ]
            }
        }
    },
```

The included options.process() takes my default banner and inserts the filename depending on the banner task I invoke.  Sometimes I will only use the default banner if you're wondering why its there and not in options.process().

The banner is placed correctly in the first file script.js:

```
/**
 * File: script.js
 *
 * Project - Version 0.1.0
 * Grunt deployed project.
 * Author: Someone - some@one.com
 * Build date: 2014-06-18 17:33:10
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Company
 * Released under the MIT license
 */

function test(){

}
```

But, in the subsequent files the file names start to stack:

```
/**
 * File: master.css
 * * File: script.js
 *
 * Project - Version 0.1.0
 * Grunt deployed project.
 * Author: Someone - some@one.com
 * Build date: 2014-06-18 17:33:10
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Company
 * Released under the MIT license
 */

@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/D\:\/htdocs\/project\/dev\/scss\/master\.scss}line{font-family:\0000320}}
html {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```